# centos7 non-interactive non-login shell source /etc/profile from cron

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, cron

I know this question has been asked thousands of times before, and at the risk of being flamed, I am still trying to wrap my head how to have both cron tasks and  cloud-init scripts read the .sh scripts under `/etc/profile.d`

According to the `/etc/profile` file

> It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
>   are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
>   /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
>   will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

So I have placed a script inside `/etc/profile.d/myVars.sh`

```
export myVar="myFolder"
```

When  using interactive scripts, works as expected with all scripts being able to read `myVar`

I have now created a cron task for reboot

```
@reboot ec2-user /home/myScript.sh
```

And that script references `${myVar}`. However the `myVar` is never read as it seems `/etc/profile.d` folder is not read by the cron task even with the `ec2-user` being set.

```
/home/myScript.sh
myvariable=$(whoami) --> reports as ec2-user
```

Is it incorrect to expect files in `/etc/profile.d` to be read when calling via a cron? I also note that using ec2 `use-data` this also fails when calling with `sudo -u ec2-user /home/myScript.sh`

How do I set the non-interactive non-login shells to read from profile.d?

Comment: Maybe try using in your crontab `/bin/bash -l -exec /etc/profile.d/myVars.sh`

Comment: thanks for the pointer, what does the `-l ` do that makes it different?

Comment: `-l` informs bash to start as a login shell.

Comment: `EXPORT` is not a thing. Use `export`.

Comment: IIUC cron uses `/bin/sh` by default and if it is BASH, then it mimics non-login non-interactive shell and does not read any initialization files. Am I right?